# Finding out which composer packages are installed globally

Tags: php, composer-php

I am working on a project where I need to determine which composer packages are installed globally and what version. What is the best way to do that on Mac?

I was hoping there was some kind of terminal command for that and I can't seem to find it.

This is what I tried:

```
php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar show
```

Tried this

```
php global composer.phar show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the parameters is wrong. `global` is not a valid parameter for the PHP interpreter, but for the `composer` application.

To see the packages installed globally on your system run:

```
php composer.phar global show
```

Or, if composer itself is installed globally:

```
composer global show
```